# React-native changing style on reload

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm just learning React-native, but I believe I understand the very basics, here I have style that applies color to a character and an icon(from a font, so another character wrapped in a component).

Everything works perfect when I edit and save the file that describes the component, but on reload the color from `styles.countIcon` is lost and it turns black.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import RideTimeIcon from './icons/RideTimeIcon';

export default class RiderCount extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
        <Text style={[
          {
            fontSize: this.props.fontSize ? this.props.fontSize : 24,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            paddingRight: 3
          },
          styles.countIcon
        ]}>
          {this.props.count ? this.props.count : 0}
        </Text>
        <RideTimeIcon icon='person' size={this.props.size} style={styles.countIcon} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

styles = StyleSheet.create({
  countIcon: {
    color: '#878787' //should be #656565 for black, 878787 white
  }
})
```

It looks like the countIcon style just disappears once I reload the app or change some file other than the component's own.

The [commit](https://github.com/kachnitel/RideTime/commit/f21f7bf805807d8fce8194392f9e0f84d61567d3) that broke it doesn't touch the component, or even its parent. It simply makes no sense to me at all. Here's what I use, and I test on Android device and simulator with the same result:

```
"expo": "^31.0.2",
"html-entities": "^1.2.1",
"react": "16.5.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",
"react-native-action-button": "^2.8.5",
"react-native-webview-leaflet": "^4.0.4",
"react-navigation": "^2.18.2"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some further poking around I found out I had used

`styles = StyleSheet.create(...)`

instead of

`const styles = StyleSheet.create(...)`.

Changing it as it's supposed to be fixes the issue.

Comment: how does const make any difference,  I also observe same issue.

Comment: @Anil I haven't looked into it much further after I fixed it. In the commit I linked I added another file where I made the same mistake, and when the file reloaded it set `styles` in the global namespace overwriting the one set before. `const` limits the scope of `styles` but I do not see how, as it is defined outside of the class/function so in my understanding it would still be global, but I guess that's explained somewhere in the JS blackbox..